# Translating Open Graph prepositions

Tags: translation, facebook-opengraph

I am developing an action using Open Graph (still a begginer at this). I'm from Brazil, so my action and objects are in portuguese. 
Everything is working fine, but I can't translate the prepositions of the message on facebook. So when I click the button on my website, the message on facebook is:

[User] seguiu **a** show **on** Rockin'Chair (that means the user followed a show on my website).

What I need to do is to change the prepositions **a** and **on** for the equivalent on portuguese, but I couldn't find out how to do it.

Thanks, Felipe